# Robot Framework not recognising an Enum class as a module

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

This is my project structure for a Robot Framework web automation:

```
src/
├── Enum/
│   └── FakerMethod.py
└── PageObjectModel/
    ├── PageObject/
    │   └── ApplyLoan.py
    ├── Resources/
    │   ├── Common.robot
    │   └── ApplyLoan.robot
    └── TestCases/
        └── symple_loans_quote_creation.robot
└── CustomLib/
    ├── CommonLib.py
    └── FakerLib.py
```

Inside my symple_loans_quote_creation.robot I am using:

```
*** Settings ***
Library         SeleniumLibrary
Library         ../../CustomLib/CommonLib.py
Library         ../../CustomLib/FakerLib.py
.
.
.
```

It gives me this error:

```
Importing test library 'src/CustomLib/FakerLib.py' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'FakerMethod'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "src/CustomLib/FakerLib.py", line 3, in <module>
import FakerMethod
```

The imports in my FakerLib.py are as follows:

```
import logging
import faker
import FakerMethod     #Present inside src/Enum
```

The FakerMethod.py goes like this:

```
from enum import Enum

class FakerMethod(Enum):
    """
        This is an enum which should be used with ../CustomLib/FakerLib.py
    """
    ABA = 'aba'
    ADD_PROVIDER = 'add_provider'
    ...
```

I have tried using:

1. import ..Enum.FakerMethod
2. from ..Enum import FakerMethod
3. Added src/Enum to the Path

But none of them worked. Robot is always failing to recognise either Enum or FakerMethod as a module

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your libraries to [module search path](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#module-search-path). From my perspective the easiest way is to add root of the project in IDE settings and during execution using `-P` command line option. After that in `FakerLib.py` use `from src.Enum.FakerMethod import FakerMethod` instead.